# How do I get this tuple to compute with my function?

Tags: python, function, iterable-unpacking

```
def heat_transfer(enter_temperature, leave_temperature, flow_rate) :
    enter_temperature -= leave_temperature
    temp_change = enter_temperature
    C = 4.19
    density = 1
    Q = (flow_rate * density) * C * temp_change
    return Q

historical_chiller_data = [(9.5, 6.300000191, 21.25596786, 34.75609756), (13.5, 6.900000095, 25.2404719, 53.28244275), (10.10000038, 7.699999809, 23.76689968, 19.91666667)]

def coefficient_performance_vs_heat_transfer(historical_data) :
    x, y, z = historical_data
    new_list = list(x)
    new_list2 = new_list.pop()
    heat_tranfer(new_list)
```

I know it's not complete but I am stuck trying to use the first three elements of the tuple in my function... Any suggestions??

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give an example of how you would call these functions?

I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but do you want `heat_transfer(*new_list)` on the last line?

Comment: So I've create the heat_transfer function to calculate heat transfer from an object which works by itself however I am trying to get a new list to compute that function and pair it with the fourth element in the current tuple. Does that make sense? I know I will need to create a loop of sorts by the end but for now I'm confused on how to get the code to compute heat_transfer and pair it with the final element. Not sure if I needed to unpack the tuple or not... The elements in the first list go (enter_temp, leave_temp, flow_rate, performance)

Comment: Does using `heat_transfer(*new_list[0:3])` on the last line do what you want? This will call the function and pass the first three elements of new_list as arguments.

Comment: Yes thank you heaps! This did what I was trying to do now I need to pair it with the remaining value from the old list. So it should give me the [(heat_transfer, coefficient,)]